# Showing that if $T$ is a Möbius transformation of the disc, $\frac{|T(z)-T(w)|}{|1-T(z)\overline{T(w)}|} = \frac{|z-w|}{|1-z\overline{w}|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

... where $z, w \in \mathbb{D}$, $\mathbb{D}$ the open unit disc. I realise that the way to start working on this is to express $T$ as $e^{i\alpha}S_a$ for some $\alpha \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $a \in \mathbb{D}$, where $S_a (z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$. Then we find that the $e^{i\alpha}$ factors disappear from the modulus on the left-hand side with handy cancellation. But after that the fractions seem to make everything a mess. I tried to prove the identity by showing $|T(z)-T(w)||1-z\overline{w}| = |z-w||1-T(z)\overline{T(w)}|$, but the fractions and terms got out of hand and I doubt it's that complicated.

Is there a simple way of proving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a point $w \in \mathbb D$ and use some additional transformations.

$Sz = \dfrac {z+w}{1 + z \bar w}$ is a  Möbius transformation on $\mathbb D$ that takes $0$ to $w$.

$Rz = \dfrac{z - Tw}{1 - z \overline{Tw}}$ is a  Möbius transformation on $\mathbb D$ that takes $Tw$ to $0$.

The composition $R \circ T \circ S$ is a  Möbius transformation on $\mathbb D$ that fixes $0$. The only such transformations are rotations, and thus $$|R(T(S(z)))| = |z|$$
$$|R(T(z))| = |S^{-1}(z)|$$
$$ \frac{|Tz - Tw|}{|1 - Tz \overline{Tw}|} = \frac{|z-w|}{|1 - z \bar w|}.$$

Comment: That's actually very clever, thanks. (Just a small typo in your last line -- the $Tw$ on the top left should be $Tz$. Only pointing it out in case someone else has the same question.)

Comment: Thanks. I can't take any credit for cleverness, though. This is standard stuff I learned in Ahlfors' book.